# JavaSmartCardIO- How to handle timeout exception of PC/SC connection?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader, pcsc

When card reader connect to card and send command, in case the time to send command and receive response is, is system notify timeout exception automatically ?
If so, What is timeout value of PC/SC ?
Or I must define that value?

Comment: Do you mean a response APDU timeout? If so, it should be handled automagically (by `WTX` for `T=1` and CLA complements for `T=0`). I have seen at least one reader having trouble with long-lasting  commands (e.g. those involving key generation) -- my bet was that the `WTX` was just ignored (vendor then fixed their firmware and the bug disappeared). Another interesting thing might be javacard's `APDU.waitExtension()` method (but I have never used it and never have seen anyone doing so) and deprecated PC/SC's `SCardSetTimeout`...Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are two methods available useful to handle exceptions when there is no card available in the reader:

> **boolean sun.security.smartcardio.TerminalImpl.waitForCardAbsent (   long
>     timeout  )  throws CardException [virtual]**
>
> Waits until a card is absent in this terminal or the timeout expires.
>   If the method returns due to an expired timeout, it returns false.
>   Otherwise it return true.
>
> If no card is present in this terminal when this method is called, it
>   returns immediately.
>
> **Parameters:** *timeout*     if positive, block for up to timeout milliseconds; if zero, block indefinitely; must not be negative
>
> **Returns:** false if the method returns due to an expired timeout, true otherwise.
>
> **Exceptions:** *IllegalArgumentException*    if timeout is negative ,*CardException*     if the operation failed
>
> Implements [javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal](http://j7a.ru/classjavax_1_1smartcardio_1_1_card_terminal.html#a8a373991eaff87f394cf5b696be8f609).
>
> Definition at line 136 of file [TerminalImpl.java](http://j7a.ru/_terminal_impl_8java_source.html).
>
> **boolean sun.security.smartcardio.TerminalImpl.waitForCardPresent (long  timeout) throws CardException [virtual]**
>
> Waits until a card is present in this terminal or the timeout expires.
>   If the method returns due to an expired timeout, it returns false.
>   Otherwise it return true.
>
> If a card is present in this terminal when this method is called, it
>   returns immediately.
>
> **Parameters:** timeout   if positive, block for up to timeout milliseconds; if zero, block indefinitely; must not be negative
>
> **Returns:** false if the method returns due to an expired timeout, true otherwise.
>
> **Exceptions:** *IllegalArgumentException*    if timeout is negative ,*CardException*     if the operation failed Implements
>   [javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal](http://j7a.ru/classjavax_1_1smartcardio_1_1_card_terminal.html#a4425d7606c9d5b745cfa11c1c5d6236f).
>
> Definition at line 132 of file [TerminalImpl.java](http://j7a.ru/_terminal_impl_8java_source.html).

---

For card's response timeout, you should first check your reader manual. some smart card readers have some additional features other than sending APDU commands to the card. This commands called "Pseudo APDU". For example I have an **ACR38** contact smart card reader and I found the following in its manual:

(From [here](http://downloads.acs.com.hk/drivers/en/REF_ACR38x_v5.0.pdf) page 14)
[image]

---

Finally if you didn't found anything useful in your reader's manual, I think you have two options:

- Implementing a `timeout` method in your multi-threaded java program that is executing always and calculate the time after sending each command and check to see if the response time is greater that a specific value or not. In cases that the time is greater than your specific value, it call the `disconnect` method and reconnect it and then you can handle it in such a way.
- Engaging with PCSC/CCID library functions to control this timeout.

Check the following links, I think you can find something useful there to aim your goal:

http://www.openscdp.org/ocf/api/de/cardcontact/opencard/terminal/smartcardio/PCSCIOControl.html

http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-perl/PCSC.html

https://github.com/credentials/smartcardjs/blob/master/ext/scuba/acr122provider/src/net/sourceforge/scuba/smartcards/ACR122TerminalFactorySpi.java

http://myacr38.blogspot.com/2007/05/program.html

Comment: Note: AFAIK the `PC_to_RDR_XfrBlock` command is on the CCID protocol level, so it is up to the card reader driver to fill the `bBWI` field value.